# Erro exited, segmentation fault ao adicionar um segundo elemento a minha lista

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Esse erro só ocorre quando eu adiciono um segundo elemento a minha lista encadeada, sei que o problema se encontra no else da função insere_contato mas não consigo identifica-lo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
  char Nome[40];
  char Telefone[15];
  char Celular[15];
  char Email[40];
  struct Agenda *Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo;
}Agenda;
Agenda *cria_agenda(){
  return NULL;
} 
Agenda *insere_contato(Agenda *Ponteiro_Inicio, char Nome_Parametro, char Telefone_Parametro, char Celular_Parametro, char Email_Parametro){
  if(Ponteiro_Inicio == NULL){
    Ponteiro_Inicio = (Agenda *) malloc(sizeof(Agenda));
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Nome[40] = Nome_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Telefone[15] = Telefone_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Celular[15] = Celular_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Email[40] = Email_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio ->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = NULL;
    return Ponteiro_Inicio;
  }else{
    Agenda *Vetor_Apontador;
    Vetor_Apontador = (Agenda *) malloc(sizeof(Agenda));
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Nome[40],Nome_Parametro);
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Telefone[15],Telefone_Parametro);
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Celular[15],Celular_Parametro);
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Email[40],Email_Parametro);
    Vetor_Apontador -> Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = Ponteiro_Inicio;
    return Vetor_Apontador;

  }
}
void lista_contatos(Agenda *Elementos){
    Agenda *Ponteiro_Para_Impressao = Elementos;
    while(Ponteiro_Para_Impressao != NULL){
    printf("\nO nome do contato é : %s", Ponteiro_Para_Impressao->Nome);
    Ponteiro_Para_Impressao = Ponteiro_Para_Impressao -> Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo;
  }
}
int main(){
  Agenda * Agnd;
  char Nome_Main[40];
  char Telefone_Main[15];
  char Celular_Main[15];
  char Email_Main[40];
  Agnd = cria_agenda();
  int Opcao = 10;
  while(Opcao != 4){
  printf("\nMenu de opcoes:\n\n");
printf("1 - Inserir Contato\n");
printf("2 - Listar Contatos\n");
printf("3 - Buscar Contato\n");
printf("4 - Sair\n");

printf("\nDigite a opcao a ser executada : ");
scanf("%d",&Opcao);
while(Opcao < 1 || Opcao > 4){
  printf("\nOpcao invalida, Digite novamente a opcao : ");
  scanf("%d",&Opcao);
        
}
switch(Opcao){
  case 1:
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("\nDigite o Nome, Telefone, Celular, e Email da pessoa nessa sequencia\n");
    fgets(Nome_Main,40,stdin);
    fgets(Telefone_Main,15,stdin);
    fgets(Celular_Main,15,stdin);
    fgets(Email_Main,15,stdin);
    Agnd = insere_contato(Agnd, Nome_Main, Telefone_Main, Celular_Main, Email_Main);
    break;
  case 2:
    lista_contatos(Agnd);
    printf("\n");
    break;

    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boa tarde, dei uma olhada melhor no seu código e fiz umas alteradiços, e com isso vou lhe falar alguns pontos:

-Primeiro: Você não estava criando uma lista, você apenas criou uma função que retorna o valor de NULL para um ponteiro. Uma Lista é um ponteiro para um ponteiro, ou seja, uma lista é um endereço que aponta para o primeiro elemento;

-Segundo: Você estava no primeiro elemento alocando a lista e retornando ele, sendo que o elemento Ponteiro_Inicio, só existe na função enquanto você aloca o primeiro elemento, depois ele vira Agen, ai na segunda alocação o programa já não sabe mais quem é Ponteiro_Inicio, ou seja, não sabe pra quem apontar, por isso segmentation foult;

-Terceiro: Mais uma dica, tente organizar melhor seu programa, criando funções menores, por exemplo, você poderia criar a função add_primeiro, apenas para adicionar o primeiro elemento, e a função add_elemento para adicionar os outros elementos;

-Quarto: Quando você estiver implementando uma estrutura de dados, deixe para implementar o seu programa depois, no caso, você implementava a lista primeiro, aí quando ela estivesse funcionando você implementava a agenda. Você pode criar a struct com uma variável qualquer, só pra testa, e o ponteiro para o próximo, ai quando você terminasse a ED você alterava e implementava sua agenda. Assim fica muito mais simples e pratico testar a ED.

Segue o código, ele não esta mais dando segmentation foult, mas esta com uns warnings de tratamento de string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
  char Nome[40];
  char Telefone[15];
  char Celular[15];
  char Email[40];
  struct Agenda *Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo;
}Agenda;

typedef struct Agenda * Lista;

//Cria Lista
Lista* cria_lista(){
  Lista* lis = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
  if(lis != NULL)
    *lis = NULL;
  return lis;
} 

int *insere_contato(Lista *lis, char Nome_Parametro, char Telefone_Parametro, char Celular_Parametro, char Email_Parametro){
    //se a lista apontar pra null vai alocar o primeiro elemento
    if((*lis) == NULL){
    Agenda *Ponteiro_Inicio = (Agenda*) malloc(sizeof(Agenda));
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Nome[40] = Nome_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Telefone[15] = Telefone_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Celular[15] = Celular_Parametro;
    Ponteiro_Inicio->Email[40] = Email_Parametro;
    //O ponteiro desse elemento para o proximo vai apontar pra NULL
    Ponteiro_Inicio ->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = NULL;
    //A lista vai agora apontar para esse elemento
    *lis = Ponteiro_Inicio;
    return 1;
  }else{
    Agenda *Vetor_Apontador;
    Vetor_Apontador = (Agenda*) malloc(sizeof(Agenda));
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Nome[40],Nome_Parametro);
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Telefone[15],Telefone_Parametro);
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Celular[15],Celular_Parametro);
    strcpy(Vetor_Apontador->Email[40],Email_Parametro);
    Vetor_Apontador->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = NULL;
    //criar uma variavel auxiliar para percorrer a lista ate o ultimo elemento
    Agenda *aux = *lis;
    while(aux->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo != NULL)
      aux = aux->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo;
    //o ponteiro do ultimo elemento vai passar apontar pra esse
    aux->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = Vetor_Apontador;
    return 1;
  }
}

void lista_contatos(Lista *lis){
    Agenda *Ponteiro_Para_Impressao = *lis;
    while(Ponteiro_Para_Impressao != NULL){
      printf("\nO nome do contato é : %s", Ponteiro_Para_Impressao->Nome);
      Ponteiro_Para_Impressao = Ponteiro_Para_Impressao -> Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo;
  }
}

int main(){
  Lista * lis;
  int x;
  lis = cria_lista();
  char Nome_Main[40];
  char Telefone_Main[15];
  char Celular_Main[15];
  char Email_Main[40];
  int Opcao = 10;
  while(Opcao != 4){
  printf("\nMenu de opcoes:\n\n");
  printf("1 - Inserir Contato\n");
  printf("2 - Listar Contatos\n");
  printf("3 - Buscar Contato\n");
  printf("4 - Sair\n");

  printf("\nDigite a opcao a ser executada : ");
  scanf("%d",&Opcao);
  while(Opcao < 1 || Opcao > 4){
    printf("\nOpcao invalida, Digite novamente a opcao : ");
    scanf("%d",&Opcao);
        
}
switch(Opcao){
  case 1:
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    printf("\nDigite o Nome, Telefone, Celular, e Email da pessoa nessa sequencia\n");
    fgets(Nome_Main,40,stdin);
    fgets(Telefone_Main,15,stdin);
    fgets(Celular_Main,15,stdin);
    fgets(Email_Main,15,stdin);
    x = insere_contato(lis, Nome_Main, Telefone_Main, Celular_Main, Email_Main);
    break;
  case 2:
    lista_contatos(lis);
    printf("\n");
    break;

    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente fazer isso se quer que seu segundo elemento seja inserido por ultimo:

```
...
Ponteiro_Inicio->Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = Vetor_Apontador;
Vetor_Apontador -> Ponteiro_Aponta_Proximo = NULL;
return Vetor_Apontador;
...
```

Comment: Não deu certo, continua com o mesmo erro! você fez ai e deu certo?